# how to remove description from menu buttons?

Tags: menus, navigation, dashboard, description

I just installed Wordpress into my server and I am currently using the "graphene" theme to test my wordpress blog. I have two pages in addition to the front page, which is "about us" and "sample page".  I noticed that if I'm using a custom menu order that is created from the "menu" section under the "Appearance" options in the dashboard, the text "this is the 'about us' page." appears under the "about us" button in the navigation menu. Removing all page text from the "about us" page didn't remove the description from the menu button.

Without custom menu, the navigation button looks like this :

|About Us|

With custom menu, the navigation button has description :

|About Us
|this is the "about us" page.|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just inatalled it and used the Custom menus and i get no description

**Never the less.. This theme have a "disable description in Header Menu" feature.**

On Your wordpress menu go to:
Graphene Options >> Display >> Navigation Menu Display Options..

Click the "disable description in Header Menu"

And your done..

Comment: Sure, happy to help :)